Updating the UI adapter immediately when the value of Int variable is changed inside the ViewModel in Kotlin
i have an interface called IInventoryItem
interface IInventoryItem : Parcelable {

    val invAuditDetailId: Int
    val invAuditItemId: Int
    
    val catalogItemId: Int
    val itemName: String 
    val partNumber: String 
    val itemUiName: String 
    
    val itemConditionCode: String
    val itemConditionName: String 
    
    val itemLotSerialId: Int
    val itemLotSerialNum: String 
    val expectedQty: Int 
    
    val itemCodes: List<IInventoryItemCodes>
    
    var detectedItemRfidCount: Int?
    var saved: Boolean?

}

and i have the adapter
class InventoryItemsAdapter(
   recyclerView: RecyclerView,
   list: MutableList\<IInventoryItem\>
   ) : BaseRecyclerAdapter\<IInventoryItem\>(recyclerView, list) {
   override fun onDispose() {
   }

   override fun getViewHolder(p0: Int, p1: LayoutInflater, p2: ViewGroup?): ViewHolder {
        return VH(AdapterInventoryingItemCardBinding.inflate(p1, p2, false))
    }
    
    inner class VH(viewBinding: ViewBinding) :
        BaseRecyclerAdapter<IInventoryItem>.ViewHolder(viewBinding) {
    
        override fun getViewBinding(): AdapterInventoryingItemCardBinding {
            return super.getViewBinding() as AdapterInventoryingItemCardBinding
        }
        override fun setValues(item: c) {
            viewBinding.apply {
                itemNameTv.text = item.itemName
                itemSerialNumberLotTv.text = item.itemLotSerialNum
                partNumberTv.text = item.partNumber
                itemUiNameTv.text = item.itemUiName
                itemConditionNameTv.text = item.itemConditionName
                expectedQtyTv.text = item.expectedQty.toString()
                detectedQtyTv.text = (item.detectedItemRfidCount ?: 0).toString()

}
}

inside the ViewModel i update the value of item.detectedItemRfidCount, which is
   val iteminventoryRepository.getInventoryItem(inventoryAudit.invAuditDetailId,codes.invAuditItemId
   ?: error("must not be null, must set at retrieve items step")
)
   for (Detected in detectedItems) {
   if (Detected.catalogItemId == item.catalogItemId) {
   Detected.detectedItemRfidCount = Detected.detectedItemRfidCount?.plus(1);
}


i want to update detectedQtyTv in the adapter immediately whenever Detected.detectedItemRfidCount value is changed , keeping the type of detectedItemRfidCount inside IInventoryItem as Int as it is , and detectedItems as MutableList as it is not changing to liveData
i tried to add a new attribute inside IInventoryItem of Type MutableLiveData<Int> , but when retrieving the item from RoomDatabase there is an issue because the return type  of inventoryRepository.getInventoryItem(inventoryAudit.invAuditDetailId,codes.invAuditItemId) is IInventoryItem not LiveData
